# Ember 'needs' property doesn't work unless you visit the needed controllers route first

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I've come across something that is either an issue with Ember's 'needs' controller property or I don't understand the proper way to achieve my goal.

The goal is to be able to have access to one or more controller's content from another controller.

So for example I have a route All Accounts that will need to have access to the contents of Bank Accounts and Credit Accounts so that it may display all accounts :)

The problem is the content is alway empty for those controllers **unless** you visit the bank and credit account routes first!

Here's a jsbin illustrating the problem:

http://jsbin.com/yubul/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A controller only has it's model automatically populated when you visit the route needing it.  Controllers can exist without models.  `needs` should generally only happen upstream, not to sibling resources/routes.

If a resource depends on another, then it should be part of your nesting structure, or fetched at the same time.

```
this.resource('accounts', function(){
  this.resource('bank-accounts');
  .....
});
```

Generally in the use case where you don't necessarily want a nested route, but you do want multiple resources I return multiple resources from the single route, or setup multiple controllers in the `setupController` hook.

## Model with multiple models (properties)

```
App.FooRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    return Em.RSVP.hash({
       cars: this.store.find('car'),
       dogs: this.store.find('dog')
    });
  }
});
```

Using the above technique your controller would be an ObjectController with two properties, `cars` and `dogs` each of which would be a collection.

## setupController set up multiple models

```
App.FooRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    return this.store.find('car');
  },
  setupController: function(controller, model){
    // this._super does the default implementation of setupController
    this._super(controller, model);
    this.controllerFor('dogs').set('model', this.store.find('dog'));
  }
});
```

Or you can do something in-between, mixing and matching.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I suspected an explanation in this direction, however how would one go about satisfying less broad use cases? for example let's say I have a settings page or some other form page that needs to access those accounts how do I handle those types of use cases where nested routes don't really apply?

Comment: The more I think on it, the 'need' to have another controller's content outside of the scope of being a nested route is not really an edge case at all. With the example: http://jsbin.com/yubul/1/edit?html,js,output. This illustrates the need to send money from one of the needed accounts, this structure wouldn't make sense as a nested route nor should be forced to be, its s a very feasible use case and their must be a way of dealing with this? Thanks for any help by the way :)

Comment: I just tossed up a few examples of mixing and matching multiple models during the same route setup.

Comment: kingpin2k That is awesome! exactly what I was looking for.. not that familiar with the RSVP hash but I'll look into it, most likely will use the setupController setup you showed.. Thanks :)